# debugging multi-source (asm and c) program with gdb (target arm) via openocd

Tags: gcc, gdb, arm, openocd

i want to debug stepwise through the sources of a program that is formed by the linker from multiple object files.

For simplicity i assume that one source is an assembly-file, where the startup routines are located and the other is a c-file. The program is build by the following makefile

```
 PREFIX=/opt/arm/bin
 LDSCRIPT=ld.script
 AS_BASEN=$(basename startup.s)
 C_BASEN=$(basename main.c)
 ASFLAGS=-g
 CCFLAGS=-g -nostartfiles
 LDFLAGS=--fatal-warnings    

 $(C_BASEN).bin: $(C_BASEN).elf
    $(PREFIX)/arm-objcopy -O binary $< $@

 $(C_BASEN).elf: $(LDSCRIPT) $(AS_BASEN).o $(C_BASEN).o
    $(PREFIX)/arm-ld $(LDFLAGS) -T $(LDSCRIPT) $(AS_BASEN).o $(C_BASEN).o -o $@

 $(C_BASEN).o: $(C_BASEN).c
    $(PREFIX)/arm-gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

 $(AS_BASEN).o: $(AS_BASEN).s Makefile
    $(PREFIX)/arm-as $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Altough i think that my problem is independet of openocd i state the openocd specific part for the sake of completeness. I initiate the debugging session with the following commands, after the openocd daemon is started.

```
 nc localhost 4444 <<eof
 soft_reset_halt
 load_image `pwd`/main.bin $memory_location
 step $memory_location
 exit
 eof
 ddd --debugger 'arm-gdb -ex "target remote localhost:3333"'
```

where $memory_location is the first address of the .text section. After `ddd` is open the program halts at the desired address and i can single step through the assembly lines as usual. Finally i arrive at the jump instruction, that jumps to the function that is located in the c-file. After one more step gdb doesn't respond anylonger whereas the program is executed.

Maybe one of you experts can give me a hint what i have to change, so that gdb switch at this point to the c-source, where i can continue the stepwise execution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try different version of these tools (if some bug inside them inhibits the expected behaviour). Try look here http://www.comsytec.com/products/gnu-binaries/gcc-binaries.html

Comment: hey thank you for your contribution. If i can't solve the problem soon, i will think about updating my arm-toolchain. Although, in my experience most of the time the mistake is not in the program itself but rather a lack of missing background information. So i will still wait for a reply some time.